# UWP project references preventing Nuget restore in VSTS build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Xamarin Forms app which I’m trying to build inside of VSTS. There is also a shared library which all projects reference and it seems this is causing issues preventing the UWP app from building.
The output from the Nuget Restore step is as follows:

```
Errors in d:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.UWP\myapp.Mobile.UWP.csproj
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Common\myapp.Common.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Common\myapp.Common.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-arm)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-arm)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Common\myapp.Common.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-arm-aot)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-arm-aot)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Common\myapp.Common.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Common\myapp.Common.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x64-aot)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x64-aot)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Common\myapp.Common.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x86)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x86)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Common\myapp.Common.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x86-aot)'.
    Unable to resolve 'd:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.csproj (>= 1.0.0)' for 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x86-aot)'.

NuGet Config files used:
    d:\a\1\s\myapp\nuget.config

Feeds used:
    C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_xamarin/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/xamarin/

Installed:
    156 package(s) to packages.config projects
    123 package(s) to d:\a\1\s\myapp\myapp.Mobile\myapp.Mobile.UWP\myapp.Mobile.UWP.csproj
```

Where `myapp.common` is the shared library and `myapp.mobile` is the Xamarin Forms shared code.

It seems VSTS is struggling to reference either of these.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this so it builds in VSTS?

Everything builds and runs fine locally – like it always does!

**EDIT**

My Build tasks are:

```
Initialize Agent
Initialize Job
Get Sources
NuGet restore **/*.sln << `The only change I've made here is to put a path to my own Nuget.Config as I'm using Syncfusion components so need to add a reference to their nuget repo aswell`
Build
Publish
```

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? Is there NuGet Tool install task (install 4.3.0) before NuGet restore task? Do you use Hosted VS2017 agent?  Could you reproduce this issue with a new simple project? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the log)

Comment: Can you post the detail log here? Try to add NuGet Tool Installer task (4.3.0) before NuGet Restore task and choose 2.* version for NuGet Restore task.

Comment: What's the result after trying it?